# modx revo: how to read content of document, but redirect when visited?

Tags: redirect, modx-revolution

I have an overview page where I load content from childpages[1]. The childpages have children[2] aswel.

What i want is when I visit a childpage[1] i'm redirected to its first child[2].

As far as I know, [[!FirstChildRedirect]] works by adding this in the content field of a parent document. But i can't do that now, because then a cannot load the content in the overview page, because it will redirect me to the first child[2] of child[1].

I hope i'm clear about this..:S

Answer (score 1):

If i'm right in what your problem is, the overview page pulls in content that actually has the redirect call so the overview page is actually then redirecting.

If so then you can either create another template that just has the firstchildredirect call in it, and for what ever page you want to redirect use that redirect template.

Or alternatively have a TV that has a single select type where you have options yes or no for redirecting. If yes then the firstchildredirect code is outputted to the template.